# Invalid Element <p4set>

Tags: perforce, nant

I am trying to connect perforce with my nant scripting:

```
<p4set client="workspace" user="ramesh" port="panda:1666" />
```

But it is showing me error like:

```
invalid Element <p4set>. Unknown task or datatype.
```

Comment: <p4set client="workspace" user="ramesh" port="panda:1666" />

Here is the code I write in my build script.

Comment: Have you included nantcontrib in your nant script using [`loadtasks`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.92/help/tasks/loadtasks.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure you've included [NAntContrib](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/) in your build script - this is what contains the [`p4set` task](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/p4set.html).

Within your `project` element in the script, use the [`loadtasks`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.92/help/tasks/loadtasks.html) task to load NAntContrib:

```xml
<project default="help">
    <loadtasks assembly="d:\path\to\nantcontrib\NAnt.Contrib.Tasks.dll" />
```